# Javascript $q Promise requests override or stacks?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, q

I am a newbie at AngularJs guys, I am sorry if I asked the wrong question but do $q promise request overrides? or stacks?
Here is a situation...
I have a function named prom `function prom{}` which returns a $q promise,
so if I call prom twice, will my first request for a promise be gone and replaced by the second call? or would it stack and will give me 2 promises?

I hope I explained myself well. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Promises are a representation of the eventual **result**, not the action. If you call the function twice, you get two requests, represented by two different Promise objects.

Comment: that means it will return 2 different object promise right?

Comment: Thank you @Madara Uchiha :), I searched Google for this one but I can't find any answers.